# Reading words from a file to a linked list in c

Tags: c

i want to read words from a file to a linked list. When i compile it there are no errors but when i run it it gives me segmentation fault. This is the first time that i'm using linked lists so it is probably a basic mistake, but i really don´t understand what i'm doing wrong. It is supposed to read the word from the file, its position and its length. This is what i have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{

    int pos;
    int size;
    char *word;
    struct node *next;

}node;


int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int i = 1;
    char dic[40];
    FILE *fp;   
    struct node *head;
    struct node *curr, *ptr;

    head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    head -> next = NULL;
    curr = head;
    ptr = head;

    fp = fopen("prob00", "r");  

    while(fscanf(fp, "%s", dic) != EOF){
        curr -> word = dic;
        curr -> pos = i;
        curr -> size = strlen(dic);
        curr -> next = NULL;
        curr = curr -> next;
        i++;
    }


    while(ptr != NULL){
        printf("palavra: %s \t tamanho: %d \t posicao %d\n", ptr -> word, ptr -> size, ptr -> pos);
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `curr -> next = NULL;
        curr = curr -> next;` now `curr` is `NULL`.

Comment: You need to `malloc()` each item, not only the first one.

Comment: This `curr -> word = dic;` will mean each node in the list is pointing to the same string - you should use `strdup` to make a copy of `dic`

Comment: Change `fscanf(fp, "%s", dic)` to `fscanf(fp, "%39s", dic)` if you want to avoid crashes and undefined behaviour.

Comment: BLUEPIXY i'm sorry i changed that already but i forgot to changed it here sorry. I put curr = curr -> next before the other one.

Comment: But dic is always changing right? In each cycle of the while the fscanf reads the next word. So why is it always reading the same?

Comment: So i have to do malloc inside the while for each node? Ok it makes sense, i wasn't thinking right. But i think it continues on giving segmentation fault

Comment: You must: malloc a new node on each iteration, and use strdup (or malloc) to allocate some memory for each word. And please learn to use a debugger! The problems are self evident if you run your program through a debugger...

Comment: Also check if `fp` is `NULL` right after `fp = fopen("prob00", "r");` and if yes, printf an error message and don't proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

A linked list is several memory area linked by pointers. You have to create these memory areas with malloc(). In your code, the next element is NULL ... it does not exist

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s", dic) != EOF){
        curr -> word = dic;
        curr -> pos = i;
        curr -> size = strlen(dic);
        curr -> next = NULL;
        curr = curr -> next;
        i++;
    }
```

You set cur->next to NULL, then you set curr to NULL. So in the next loop, the first line curr->word can't be possible because there is no word field in this NULL area

Here is an example, a function to insert a new node in the list, at the end of the list. In this example you have to give to the function the address of the first element i called head (head or tail, it depends on you).

```
void    insert_at_end(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *new_element;

    new_element = malloc(sizeof(*new_element)); // in real life you need to check malloc's return 
    new_element->next = NULL;    // because this is the new last element, next is NULL

    // new_element->pos = x   // initialize datas
    // new_element->size = x
    // new_element->word = x

    while (head->next != NULL) // we are going to the last element in the list
        head = head->next;

    head->next = new_element; // connection between the last element and the new one
}
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Please elaborate, otherwise it will most likely be downvoted.

Comment: I have to get 50 reps to comment, i'm almost there :)

Comment: I know, i´m sorry about that, i forgot to changed it here but i changed it in my code before. now it is first the curr = curr -> next and then the curr -> next = NULL